# New expo init bare project not building for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

Started by using `expo init` app and used bare-minimum typescript template, the app is not building using `react-native run-ios`, but works if `expo start` in the Expo-go app.

here is the error code:

```
info Installing "/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-ccluoxcwmsrveqavqitrwaszccss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproject"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2D6990A9-04F6-4391-BFA3-BFF2AA6890A5/data/Bundle/Application/2B342978-B520-410C-ABB0-F5961248B7BF/myproject.app/myproject : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
        Failed to chmod /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2D6990A9-04F6-4391-BFA3-BFF2AA6890A5/data/Bundle/Application/2B342978-B520-410C-ABB0-F5961248B7BF/myproject.app/myproject : No such file or directory
info Launching "org.name.myproject"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "org.name.myproject" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "org.name. myproject" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "org.name.myproject" is unknown to FrontBoard.
        Application "org.name.myproject" is unknown to FrontBoard.
```

When app is launched in Xcode the build is successful but the app don't load on simulator and I get this error message:

[image]

the config:

```
Expo CLI 4.1.6 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.0.1
      Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.15.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.11 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.7, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 24, 27, 28, 29
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.7/11E801a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~40.0.0 => 40.0.1 
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-native: ~0.63.4 => 0.63.4 
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18 
    Expo Workflow: bare
```